# Batch: Filter filename

Tags: batch-file

I have lot file that need to filter before move to other folder. 
The filter condition:

```
[PEQ]*_[+-][1-9][0-9]_[P-R][0-9]_*[._][0-9]*
```

Example of filename:

```
P101_+19_R0_3.0_QA.txt
```

I try to apply the  filter in batch script but nothing happen.
Am i correctly defined the filter?

My script:

```
SET _ext1=txt
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%f in (%_source%\[PEQ]*_[+-][1-9][0-9]_[P-R][0-9]_*[._][0-9]*.%_ext1%) do (
    echo %%f  >> %LOG%
SET _path=%%~df%%~pf
    echo !_path! >> %LOG%

SET _filename=%%~nf
echo !_filename! >> %LOG%

echo. >> %LOG%
echo Processing !_filename! >> %LOG%
IF EXIST !_path!!_filename!*.%_ext1% (
    copy /Y "!_path!!_filename!*.%_ext1%" "%_target%" >> %LOG%

)
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: @LotPings is'nt if we put [PEQ] , the first character of file is either P or E or Q? Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Thats right, but your filter (?RegEx?) expects after any number `*` of `[PEQ]` an underscore `_` You can use RegEX in batch only as argument of findstr or other tools (ported sed,grep) or PowerShell. Batch uses only wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you understand the difference between a wildcard `*` matching any number of any chars and the RegEx `*` which means any number (also zero) of the previous match. Together with the RE `.` any char `.*` will resemble the wildcard `*`

```
@Echo off & SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET _ext1=txt
for /f "delims=" %%f in (
    'dir /B "%_source%\*_*_*_*.%_ext1%" ^| Findstr /i "%_source%\[PEQ]*_[+-][1-9][0-9]_[P-R][0-9]_.*[._][0-9]*.%_ext1%" '
) do (
    echo %%f  >> %LOG%
    SET _path=%%~df%%~pf
    echo !_path! >> %LOG%

    SET _filename=%%~nf
    echo !_filename! >> %LOG%

    echo. >> %LOG%
    echo Processing !_filename! >> %LOG%
    IF EXIST !_path!!_filename!*.%_ext1% (
        copy /Y "!_path!!_filename!*.%_ext1%" "%_target%" >> %LOG%
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

You should first test the line with the dir and findstr in an open cmd window,
then without the escaping `^` and surrounding `'`

```
dir /B "%_source%\*_*_*_*.%_ext1%"
```

If this fits as a first selection add

```
dir /B "%_source%\*_*_*_*.%_ext1%" | Findstr /i "%_source%\[PEQ]*_[+-][1-9][0-9]_[P-R][0-9]_.*[._][0-9]*.%_ext1%"
```

And vary your RegEx until it does what you want.

Remember that findstr RegEx capabilities are quite limited.